# Reballing / Estimate size of solder balls for BGA-132 NAND chip with 1mm pitch and diameter of pads 0.3mm (Kingston FB64B08UCT1-0D)

Tags: soldering, bga

For reballing, I need to estimate the size of original solder balls for the **Kingston FB64B08UCT1-0D** BGA-132 NAND chip coming from a Kingston ssdnow 256GB SSD, model RBU-SC180DS37/256GH.

Another SSD, the Kingson A400 240GB uses the same PCB board and same NAND chip.
According to [this article](https://www.digit.in/reviews/pc-components/kingston-a400-ssd-240-gb-review-125099.html), and assuming that the manufacturer remained same, the Kingston- branded FB64B08UCT1-0D would in fact be Toshiba 15mm 2D planar TLC NAND.
There are four such chips on afore mentioned 240GB / 256GB SSD models, so that each chip is 64GB.

**I could not find any datasheet** for the Kingston branded chip, **nor could I find which would be the equivalent Toshiba-branded chip**. A datasheet would possibly mention the recommended ball size.

**What I have measured:**

- the pitch is 1mm
- the diameter of pads, on both the PCB and NAND chip is 0.3mm
- the diameter of (the remaining part of the) solder balls on the PCB board is around **0.4-0.45 mm** for most ones, with a spherical or almost spherical shape. The diameter of the largest ones (when they didn't merge with another sphere) is around 0.5mm.
- the diameter of the solder ball residues on the NAND chips is mostly ranges from **0.3mm to 0.35 mm**. Almost flat drops are usually 0.3mm, whilst 0.35mm is more common for almost spherical drops.

To facilitate the reballing, I have the SSD:1 V1.0 stencil from Amaoe. For the BGA-132 layout, the side the square opening for each ball is 0.6mm.

I assume that the original solder balls were 0.50 or 0.55 mm.

I attempted an **estimation by summing the average volumes of remaining solder on PCB pads and NAND pads**, which rather suggest the first value of 0.50 mm:

Volume of sphere = 4 * Pi * R3 / 3

**A.** For the PCB, with sphere diameters from 0.4 to 0.45 mm, volume ranges from 0.033
mm3 to 0.048 mm3. Using a **mean diameter of 0.425**, the volume of the sphere is **0.04 mm3**.

**B.** For the NAND, with sphere diameters from 0.3 to 0.35 mm, volume ranges from 0.014 mm3 to 0.022 mm3. Using a **mean diameter of 0.325 mm**, the volume of the sphere is **0.018 mm3**.

**C.** Summing the remaining volume of a solder ball on PCB and NAND chip (A+B): 0.058. --> Radius = 0.24mm --> **Diameter ~ 0.5mm**.

**Nota bene:** I also observed that by the desoldering, some small balls rolled out from the circuit, so that there is some loss of material which has not been taken into account.

Although my estimation suggests 0.5 mm solder balls, but **more information / ideas / rules of thumb / datasheets are welcome**.

**Also, does a 10% difference in the seletion of the solder balls diameter really matter?**
The reballing will be for data recovery and is not thought as a repair that has to lasts over the long term.